# Deploy .war file in docker container: No main manifest attribute in app.war

Tags: java, docker, gradle, manifest

I have a .war-file of my java application and would like to deploy that to a docker container.

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM java:8
EXPOSE 8080
ADD /App.war app.war
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.war"]
```

I have my `App.war` in the same directory.

When I want to run it with the following command:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -t app
```

it throws the following exception:

```
no main manifest attribute, in app.war
```

However, when I inspect app.war, there's a manifest in /META-INF/MANIFEST.MF stating the following options:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Start-Class: com.package.app.AppMainClass
Spring-Boot-Classes: WEB-INF/classes/
Spring-Boot-Lib: WEB-INF/lib/
Spring-Boot-Version: 1.4.0.RELEASE
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher
```

So as far as I understand the error message it states that a Main-Class attribute is missing in the manifest (which is impossible because it's there).
I have also tried adding the real class as Main-Class.

That led to the same error.

Can someone please help me back on track?

Comment: Why do you need to deploy it as war? I see you're using the archive as an uberjar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all don't build a spring boot project as WAR. You would only need WAR if you had some old ancient project which forced you to deploy the app to a web server/servlet container. You'll need to remove war related logic from your build script.

Second. Make sure you're building the project correctly. If it is gradle, you need to build it with `./gradlew build`, for maven use `mvn package`. That will package your archive as an uberjar - including all needed dependencies and making the proper archive structure.

Find more details on how to put a spring boot application to Docker [in the user guides](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/).

If and only if by some strange occurrences you need to build it as WAR and run it as an executable archive make sure you do it [using the war-plugin provided by spring boot](https://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/) (not the built in war plugin). That's the only working way to build an executable war archive.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the hints! I'm already building the project with ./gradlew build. The result I'm getting is a /build folderv in project root with a couple of folders. Among them I have a ./libs folder with a .war and .war.original file. Where do I get the uberjar?

Comment: JAR file will be at the same place. But you need to make sure your build actually generates jar files. It does this by default, but your build script contains an instruction that makes it generate WAR instead. You need to remove that instruction (can't say more without seeing your `build.gradle`). Or once again the simplest way would be to check what's different in your setup in comparison with the one from the guide https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/

Comment: Ok got it. And, in this .jar I then have the webapp as well, right? (if I put it into src/main/webapp)

Comment: You'll have them for sure. Nothing changes from functional perspective.